# How to run Webview on iOS in Flutter

Tags: flutter, webview

I have used these to libs:

```
  webview_flutter: ^2.0.8
  webview_cookie_manager: ^2.0.0
```

and I am trying to show a web page in a section in my App. It worked well on Android so far but when I try to run it on iOS it gives me an error. Here is my console log:

> Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 12 Pro Max in debug mode... Running
> pod install...                                           1,097ms
> CocoaPods' output: ↳
> Preparing
>
> ```
> Analyzing dependencies
>
> Inspecting targets to integrate
>   Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)
>
> Fetching external sources
> -> Fetching podspec for `Flutter` from `Flutter`
> -> Fetching podspec for `webview_cookie_manager` from
> `.symlinks/plugins/webview_cookie_manager/ios`
> -> Fetching podspec for `webview_flutter` from
> `.symlinks/plugins/webview_flutter/ios`
>
> Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
>   CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local
>   because checking is only perfomed in repo update
> [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod
> "webview_cookie_manager":
>   In Podfile:
>     webview_cookie_manager (from
>     `.symlinks/plugins/webview_cookie_manager/ios`)
>
> Specs satisfying the `webview_cookie_manager (from
> `.symlinks/plugins/webview_cookie_manager/ios`)` dependency were found, but
> they required a higher minimum deployment target.
>
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:32
> 8:in `raise_error_unless_state'
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:31
> 0:in `block in unwind_for_conflict'
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:30
> 8:in `tap'
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:30
> 8:in `unwind_for_conflict'
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:68
> 4:in `attempt_to_activate'
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:25
> 4:in `process_topmost_state'
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:18
> 2:in `resolve'
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolver.rb:43:i
> n `resolve'
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:94:
> in `resolve'
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analy
> zer.rb:1074:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.
> rb:64:in `section'
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analy
> zer.rb:1072:in `resolve_dependencies'
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analy
> zer.rb:124:in `analyze'
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:41
> 4:in `analyze'
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:23
> 9:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.
> rb:64:in `section'
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:23
> 8:in `resolve_dependencies'
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:16
> 0:in `install!'
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/command/install
> .rb:52:in `run'
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in
> `run'
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:i
> n `run'
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/bin/pod:55:in `<top
> (required)>'
> /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
> /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
> ```
>
> Error output from CocoaPods: ↳
>
> ```
> [!] Automatically assigning platform `iOS` with version `9.0` on target
> `Runner` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for
> this target in your Podfile. See
> `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.
> ```
>
> Error running pod install Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro
> Max.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: May be, do `flutter clean && cd ios && rm Podfile Podfile.lock && rm -rf Pods/ && cd .. && flutter pub get` and then run the project again.

Comment: @Pushpendra unfortunately it didn't change anything